# Where is Python used? I read about it a lot on Reddit

Tags: python

I have downloaded the Pyscripter and learning Python. But I have no Idea if it has any job value , especially in India. I am learning Python as a Hobby. But it would be comforting to know if Python programmers are in demand in India.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everywhere. It's used [extensively by google](http://panela.blog-city.com/python_at_google_greg_stein__sdforum.htm) for one.

See [list of python software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_software) for more info, and also [who uses python on the web?](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/www8-py-www/sld010.htm)

Answer (score 10):

In many large companies it is a primary scripting language.
Google is using it along with Java and C++ and almost nothing else.
Also many web pages are built on top of python and Django. 
Another place is game development. Many games have their engines written in C++ but all the logic in Python.

In other words it is one of the most valuable tools.

This might be of interest for you as well:

- [Is Python good for big software projects (not web based)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753/is-python-good-for-big-software-projects-not-web-based)
- [Are there any good reasons why I should not use Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371966/are-there-any-good-reasons-why-i-should-not-use-python)
- [What did you use to teach yourself python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111857/what-did-you-use-to-teach-yourself-python)

Comment: Good Links Lew. This should keep me busy for months. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot JavaScript in the list of Google-sanctioned languages.

Answer (score 4):

It definitely has job value. For instance Google requires it. Have a look at [Google openings in India](http://www.google.co.in/support/jobs/bin/topic.py?dep_id=1054&loc_id=1100&topic=1054):

> Excellent programming skills in at
>   least one of the following languages:
>   C, C++, Java or Python (C++/Python
>   preferred)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about India, but you can get a decent overview of available Python jobs on the python.org jobs page [here](http://www.python.org/community/jobs/).

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at Mark Pilgrim's excellent book "[Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.org/)" which is available for download under GNU Free Documentation License.

HTH

cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

In 10 years of web development I've had 1 client have me write an email parsing app with it.  Not that it doesn't get used, but I've seen Ruby/php/.net way more often in the wild.

Edit:
From the other posts if you plan on working at Google, it sounds like the language to learn - LOL!

Comment: your clients ask what language you should use? that sucks

Comment: no - they generally have an infrastructure - we don't dictate their project requirements to them.

Answer (score 1):

It's juste one example but I know it is widely used in large scientific institutions with high tech machinery where non-programmers (typically physicists) need quick prototypes or tools to cover their data collection/processing needs. The easy-to access scripting language aspect clearly plays its role here. So I don't know about building a career out of that only but I'd definitely say that knowing Python is a very valuable asset on your resume, it'll strengthen your "smell of usefulness".

Answer (score 0):

The google app engine lets you use python (or Java).  I HIGHLY recommend that you check it out.  If you want to have a FREE website with a database (actually a datastore but it works much like a database) using python, THIS IS IT.  It scales up too.  If you start to get enough traffic you would have to start paying for the usage it requires.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview.html

You could make your own python based site and run some ads.  Voila, make some money.  Also, I'm sure google could be impressed by some good python because I hear they use it for much of their own sites.